# Email intent android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Well, im trying to make my app sending an email with infromation entered in the entry text elements, but when I try it in the phone it says "No application can perform this action. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
View boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    boton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.enviar).getId())
    {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String mailId= "villasantdesign@gmail.com";
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mailId});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Consulta Técnica");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etlugar.getText()); etfecha.getText(); etcable.getText(); etqe.getText(); etantena.getText(); etampli.getText(); etmodulo.getText();}{
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Envío"));
        }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to configure an email account in your default `Email` application or in any other email clients like `Gmail`,so that It can redirect the user to that application and let him send the email.

**Solution:**

The below snippet works absolutely fine.

```
 View boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    boton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.enviar).getId())
    {


    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromParts("mailto","villasantdesign@gmail.com", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Consulta Técnica");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etlugar.getText());     
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Envío"));



}}}
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: I have my account already, I configured another one and it keeps giving me the message.

Comment: If error is about `No application can perform this action`,Most probably you are missing configuration of email account.Because this code works fine for me across all versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install Email App to you phone, like Gmail, or Android can not find any App to receive that intent. **And you should change Intent.ACTION_SEND to Intent.ACTION_SENDTO**

Comment: I have my account already, I configured another one and it keeps giving me the message.

Comment: Did you try to change Intent.ACTION_SEND to Intent.ACTION_SENDTO?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up mime-type:

emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

& change `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` instead of `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` to get only the list of e-mail clients, with no facebook or other apps. Just the email clients.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure an email account in your default Email application.

```
 Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    email.setType("plain/text");
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { abc@gmail.com) });
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                            "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` intent is the mail sending intent.`Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Envío")` will going to prompt  you to select the mail sending application from the collection of configured sending applications like Gmail App. if no mail is configured in your device or simulator it will reply like no app can perform this action.